# How to see if type is instance of a class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Short form (this will solve my problem one way at least)

How can I do something like this:

```
try_to_show :: a -> String
try_to_show val = if (val is instance of Show) (show val) else "Cannot show"
```

---

I'm probably doing this completely wrong (the unhaskell way); I'm just learning so please let me know if there's a better way to approach this.

Context: I'm writing a bunch of tree structures. I want to reuse my `prettyprint` function for binary trees. Not all trees can use the generic `Node`/`Branch` data type though; different trees need different extra data. So to reuse the `prettyprint` function I thought of creating a class different trees would be instances of:

```
class GenericBinaryTree a where
    is_leaf :: a -> Bool
    left :: a -> a
    node :: a -> b
    right :: a -> a
```

This way they only have to implement methods to retrieve the left, right, and current node value, and prettyprint doesn't need to know about the internal structure.

Then I get down to here:

```
prettyprint_helper :: GenericBinaryTree a => a -> [String]
prettyprint_helper tree
    | is_leaf tree = []
    | otherwise = ("{" ++ (show (node tree)) ++ "}") : (prettyprint_subtree (left tree) (right tree))
        where
            prettyprint_subtree left right =
                ((pad "+- " "|  ") (prettyprint_helper right)) ++ ((pad "`- " "   ") (prettyprint_helper left))
            pad first rest = zipWith (++) (first : repeat rest)
```

And I get the `Ambiguous type variable 'a0' in the constraint: (Show a0) arising from a use of 'show'` error for `(show (node tree))`

Here's an example of the most basic tree data type and instance definition (my other trees have other fields but they're irrelevant to the generic `prettyprint` function)

```
data Tree a
    = Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
    | Leaf
instance GenericBinaryTree (Tree a) where
    is_leaf Leaf = True
    is_leaf _ = False
    left (Branch left node right) = left
    right (Branch left node right) = right
    node (Branch left node right) = node
```

---

I could have defined `node :: a -> [String]` and deal with the stringification in each instance/type of tree, but this feels neater. In terms of `prettyprint`, I only need a string representation, but if I add other generic binary tree functions later I may want the actual values.

So how can I write this to work whether the node value is an instance of `Show` or not? Or what other way should I be approaching this problem? In an object oriented language I could easily check whether a class implements something, or if an object has a method.

---

I can't use something like

```
prettyprint :: Show a => a -> String
```

Because it's not the tree that needs to be showable, it's the value inside the tree (returned by function `node`) that needs to be showable. I also tried changing `node` to `Show b => a -> b` without luck (and a bunch of other type class/preconditions/whatever/I don't even know what I'm doing anymore).

Comment: you could make everything an instance of show: `instance Show a where show _ = "<no show>"`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do the first solution you mentioned in your question. What you can do is try something like:

```
class GenericBinaryTree t where
    is_leaf :: t a -> Bool
    left :: t a -> t a
    node :: t a -> a
    right :: t a -> t a

prettyprint_helper :: (GenericBinaryTree f, Show a) => f a -> [String]
```

Here we are using the type class to specify a way the tree can be navigated, this solves your problem that the trees can have different structure. Next problem was how to show node values, that is solved by adding the `Show` type class constrain in the `prettyprint_helper` singnature. `GenericBinaryTree` instance implementation:

```
instance GenericBinaryTree Tree where
  is_leaf Leaf = True
  is_leaf _ = False
  left (Branch left node right) = left
  right (Branch left node right) = right
  node (Branch left node right) = node
```

Comment: Seems great, only problem now is I get `Ambiguous type variable in constraint` for `prettyprint (Leaf) = GenericBinaryTree.prettyprint Leaf` since the `Leaf` constructor doesn't have anything to identify its type parameter... how can I work around this?

Comment: Since the `Leaf` type doesn't need to be shown, is there a way to add some sort of "either or" constraint? Since it'll either be a Leaf, and we don't need to show it, or it will be a Branch, in which case the second type parameter needs to be showable.

Comment: @Raekye: Can you add the code for `prettyprint` so that your comment is more clear?

Answer (score 2):

In your class you have `node :: a -> b` where `a` is fixed to be something instantiating `GenericBinaryTree` but `b` is... truly anything. Without any constraints at all on it, you end up with a value that you cannot use at all, let alone `show`.

The `node :: Show b => a -> b` method provides a constraint that `b` must be `Show`able but then you run into a second problem: we still don't know, concretely, what `b` is!

In particular, this is why it's rarely a good idea to have unconstrained type variables in a `class` declaration. You see them in places like

```
instance Alternative f where
  empty :: f a
```

to suggest that we have the ability to create an `f` container which has zero elements inside it... so it might as well take any type `f a` for any `a` whatsoever.

A solution might be to use MultiParamTypeClasses

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class GenericBinaryTree b a | a -> b where
  is_leaf :: a -> Bool
  left :: a -> a
  node :: a -> b
  right :: a -> a

showNode :: (Show b, GenericBinaryTree b a) => a -> String
showNode = show . node
```

Compiles just fine.

Comment: Interesting. How do I define the instance then? I tried `instance GenericBinaryTree (Tree a) a where ...` and it says "Illegal instance declaration for..." I did include the pragma in both files. Also, is there a way to accomplish the general goal without MultiParamTypeClasses? And is there a way to solve the "short form" question (see top of question)

Comment: @Raekye, if you are using exactly this typeclass, then swap its type parameters: `instance GenericBinaryTree a (Tree a) where`. Don't know why they are reversed.

Comment: @Raekye, yes, there is a way (though somewhat limited compared to extensions), see Ankur's answer. As for "short form", no, it is impossible to do it. Haskell uses type erasure, and there is no way to check types in runtime directly. It may be possible to do it, however, with `Typeable` type class, I don't know.

Comment: In general, no, even Typeable cannot recover typeclass information. Typeclasses are all resolved at compile time and transformed into explicitly threaded method dictionaries. Typeable can only recover concrete type information—the information you can see if you `-ddump-deriv` your derived Typeable classes.